# Filter only return 1 or 0 result with datas

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 (typescript), I am using the method filter

```
The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
```

But When I use `"or"` I only get `1 or 0`  result ...

Code:

```
 public filter(url: string, id: number): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(map(param => {

  console.log('date' , param[1]['params'].filter(dato =>   new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString() === '15/3/2016'));


  let filter = param[1]['params'].filter(dato => dato.id === id)
    || param[1]['params'].filter(dato =>   new Date(dato.startdatevalidity).toLocaleDateString() === '15/3/2016')
    || param[1]['params'].filter(dato =>  new Date(dato.enddatevalidity).toLocaleDateString() === '15/4/2016');

  console.log('filter' , filter );

  return filter;
}
));
  }
```

In console.log (date) I get Array 10, OK !! good.

But in let filter I have 2 problems:

1º problem: "If I send id, ONLY filter with id and return 1 result.

2º problem: "If I don't send Id , " I get 0 result.

In any case I should get My array 10 the console.log(date) in my let filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make much sense.

`array.filter()` returns an array. An array is always truthy.

So your code does basically

```
let filter = someArray || someOtherArray || someYetOtherArray;
```

And the result of that will always be `someArray`, since an array is truthy.

You probably want, instead

```
let filter = array.filter(element => someCheck(element) || someOtherCheck(element) || yetAnotherCheck(element))
```

which will return all the elements that pass at least one of the three predicates.